# PHP MYSQL GET method and two categories

Tags: php, mysql, get

if i have a HTTP GET method url like this http://www.mywebsite.com/page.php?q=Banana&NewYork where Banana is
fruit category and NewYork is city category on my mysql database, how can i handle that with mysql request
so that in page.php will show the specific url request

```
php
$q= ($_GET['q']);
$q = htmlspecialchars($q);
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($q);

mysql
$req = $db->prepare ('SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ...');
$req->execute();
```

Thanks to everybody.

Comment: What do you mean? You can get your "fruit" category with $_GET['q'], as you did, and your "city" categorie with $_GET['c'] IF you fix the error in the URL and make page.php?q=Banana&c=NewYork

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your URL look like this: `...page.php?fruit=Banana&city=NewYork` you can use the following example code.

Also you should use prepared statements instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`.

```
<?php

$fruit = $_GET['fruit'];
$city = $_GET['city'];

//mysql
//Prepare the query and create a stmt
$req = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE fruit = ? AND city = ?");

//$req contains now a prepared statement - binding the parameters
//because at both "?" there are strings, there need to be "ss"
//The value of $fruit will be placed at the first ? - $city will be placed at the second ?
$req->bindParam("ss",$fruit,$city);

//Execute the statement
$req->execute();
?>
```

Comment: +1 For the use of prepared statements. Unlike the @user3052781 answer which I down-voted due to the lack of security and possible SQL Injections.

Answer (score 2):

To save yourself parsing one whole query string, use two parameters in the URL such as:

```
?fruit=Banana&city=NewYork
```

You can then use `$_GET['fruit']` and `$_GET['city']` to retrieve those values.

You then need to correctly sanitize the input before putting them into the query, I see you are using `mysql_real_escape_string` and `mysql_query` but this are not recommended due to deprecation on the `mysql_*` functions.

Look in to `mysqli_*` or even better, using prepared statements. There any many resources available on SO, and you will find a lot more on search engines.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$fruit = (isset($_GET['fruit'])) ? $_GET['fruit'] : '';
$city  = (isset($_GET['city'])) ? $_GET['fruit'] : '';

$fruit = htmlspecialchars($fruit);
$fruit = mysql_real_escape_string($fruit);

$city = htmlspecialchars($city);
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($city);

//mysql
$req = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE fruit = '".$fruit."' AND city = '".$city."'");
$req->execute();
```

But the url query should be `http://www.mywebsite.com/page.php?fruit=Banana&city=NewYork`

EDIT:

At the very start, I check if $_GET for fruit and city are set and if so, get their values, if not put '' or empty string.

Then I sanitized the url input via htmlspecialchars and mysql_real_escape_string.

Then we prepare a sql statement that looks for fruit and city then execute.

Comment: Explain what you're doing instead of throwing "working code" at somebody.

Answer (score -1):

your url should be like this page.php?fruit=bannana&city=newyork

after that you have to get this two variable like

```
<?php 

$fruits = $_GET['fruit'];


$city = $_GET['city'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from tablename where fruits = '".$fruits."' and city = '".$city."'");

$res = mysql_fetch_array($query);


?>
```

hope it will help you :)

Comment: Possible SQL Injections with this syntax!